# Merge objects only by the ID

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays that I want to merge by the id of the objects that in the arrays (2 different objects):

```
$object1 = new User();
$object2 = new User();
$object3 = new AdminUser();
$object4 = new AdminUser();


$object1->id = "1234";
$object1->name = "testUser1";
$object2->id = "34553";
//the id is like user1 but the username is different
$object3->id = "1234";
$object3->name = "testUser2";
$object4->id = "44234";

$array1  = [$object1,$object2];
$array2  = [$object3,$object1,$object4];
```

my wanted result is :

```
[$object1,$object2,$object4];
```

i tried :`array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);`
and I also tried :

```
$result = array_merge( $array1, $array2 );
$result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $result)));
```

but it didn't work

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) after merging those 2 arrays:

```
$mergedObjects = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$result = array_reduce($mergedObjects, function ($carry, $user) {
    if (!isset($carry[$user->id])) {
        $carry[$user->id] = $user;
    }
    return $carry;
}, array());
```

Answer (score 0):

array functions are only ment for arrays, they do not parse anything inside objects that are within arrays. What you could do is push the object ids as array keys:

```
$mainArray = array();
foreach($objects as $object){ //or do it for every object if you create them manually
    array_merge($mainArray, array($object->id => $object);
}
```

If the keys ( ids ) are duplicate, the latest takes priority.